# Elasticsearch docker image - use free port

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm struggling to get the docker image configuration right. What I would like for my docker container is to run on a random, kernel-selected port using these parameters: `--publish 0:9200 --publish 0:9300`.

The problem I'm experiencing is that I also need to set these parameters: `-e "http.port=PORT" -e "transport.publish_port=ANOTHER_PORT"`, if I want to use ports different to default (9200, 9300).

That is something I obviously cannot do, because I don't know these ports at the time I run my container. I thought removing these parameters should solve the issue and make Elasticsearch bind to ports that are available to it (based on private ports in use). That's unfortunately not the case.

Is there any solution to that problem or is it just Elasticsearch image that is uncapable of running with random port.

Comment: how will you get random port while you are build docker image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I would assume that docker container has a pair of `<random port>:9200` ports, therefore ES running within that container should bind to 9200 and docker would expose this port as `<random port>`. But it does not work - I can't connect to elasticsearch instance using port `<random port>`.

Comment: It works. Can you share Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm using official elasticsearch image.

Comment: Hi. how did you solved your problem?

Comment: Well, I decided to change my approach completely and I'm now using docker-compose and virtual network (this way I can use default ports without running into conflicts between multiple Elasticsearch instances, each in its own network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run docker image with `--publish-all` flag. This will expose all ports to random ports.

```
$ docker run --publish-all -d elasticsearch:5.6-alpine
```

Lets check,

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
cea8026ead0b        elasticsearch:5.6-alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:32778->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32777->9300/tcp   small_ride
```

Ports are exposed as

```
0.0.0.0:32778->9200/tcp
0.0.0.0:32777->9300/tcp
```

You can now connect to your elasticsearch with `32778` this port

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:32778
{
  "name" : "Ui-_rXY",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "du5_h-sQSbilsYq0jQnyNA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.6",
    "build_hash" : "7d99d36",
    "build_date" : "2018-01-09T23:55:47.880Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

In this case, elasticsearch running on `9200`. But if you want to change its default port, you need to modify its `elasticsearch.yml`.
See [Original elasticsearch docker repository](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/tree/e7ccd59cec2328020c005d94010d91b95ee7f291/5/alpine)

You need to set port as

```
http.port: ${HTTP_PORT}
transport.tcp.port: ${TCP_PORT}
```

And when you will run docker, you need to provide this ENV.

```
$ docker run -e HTTP_PORT=9233 -e TCP_PORT=9317 -d elasticsearch:5.6-alpine
```

Now, your elasticsearch will run in port `9233` and `9317`

Hope, this will help.

Comment: Thank you @aerokite. It's useful and I will mark it as correct, since it does answer my question (although if you see my other comment I decided not to follow that approach)

Comment: You are welcome. I appreciate it. For multiple instance, docker-composer is better.